# Octave io package installation on macOS

Tags: macos, package, config, octave

I've searched the web high and low to no avail so I'm resorting to asking here..

I want to install the io package to Octave 4.4.1 on MacOS Catalina (10.15.5). I've tried installing directly from the Forge and again from the .gz file, but I get the following error every time:

```
configure: error: in `/var/folders/rh/y2fddn916sg3v_8pkln9z7jr0000gq/T/oct-JsL8yQ/io-2.6.1/src':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
checking for mkoctfile... /Applications/Octave-4.4.1.app/Contents/Resources/usr/Cellar/octave-octave-app@4.4.1/4.4.1/bin/mkoctfile-4.4.1
checking for octave-config... /Applications/Octave-4.4.1.app/Contents/Resources/usr/Cellar/octave-octave-app@4.4.1/4.4.1/bin/octave-config-4.4.1
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no

pkg: error running the configure script for io.
error: called from
    configure_make at line 82 column 9
    install at line 184 column 7
    pkg at line 437 column 9
```

I know I need to provide the config.log file to troubleshoot but I cannot for *my life* find this anywhere. So:

1. Where do I find the config file?
2. How do I get io to install?

I don't pretend to know anything about programming so less-technical answers appreciated if possible. I installed Octave using the native mac app version from the website.

Comment: more random thoughs than an answer per se, but, presumably octave 'cleans up' after an unsuccessful attempt. you're more likely to find the config.log file if you download the tar.gz file rather than install directly from forge, and then try co halt execution before clean up occurs, or something like that. Presumably _during_ installation octave creates temporary files in the current or target directory, that it later cleans up? Also, regardless of config.log, perhaps this simply relates to permissions / your c++ compiler. do you have one installed? is there a `c++` binary in your path?

Comment: I looked into the compiler, tried to identify mine in terminal; terminal was giving me an `invalid active developer path` error. I ran the solution on [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a) in terminal to install the Command Line Tools Package. I tried running the `pkg install -forge io` command in Octave again and it worked!. Thanks @TasosPapastylianou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
...
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
```

This generally means that either you have Xcode installed but have not yet run it and accepted the EULA (which you must do once before using Xcode for anything, including command line work), and/or don't have the Xcode Command Line Tools installed (which you can do using `sudo xcode-select --install`).

That being said, there are outstanding issues with installing several Octave Forge packages on macOS. If you have further trouble with it, you can drop by [the Octave.app repo on GitHub](https://github.com/octave-app/octave-app/issues) for support.